# AWS S3 & NodeJS - xhr error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I am trying follow along this tutorial on uploading files to Amazon S3 with NodeJS and have gotten hung up on an error that occurs on the client side of the code, but I'm pretty sure is part of my route. The 404 error that appears is on the `xhr.send()` request to the server in the `sign_request` function. The information from my file that is logged at the GET is correct `file:138 GET http://localhost:3000/sign?file_name=gtm-value.png&file_type=image/png 404 (Not Found)`, which makes me think that it has something to do with my route setup.

view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        {{> app/app-head}}
    </head>
    <body>
        {{> app/app-navigation}}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <form action="/create" method="post">
                <input type="file" name="fileAttachment" id="image"> 
                    <img id="preview">
<button type="submit" id="button">Create Image</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function upload(file, signed_request, url, done) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
                xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    done()
                };
            };
            xhr.send(file);
            }

        function sign_request(file, done) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "/sign?file_name=" + file.name + "&file_type=" + file.type);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    done(response);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        };

        document.getElementById("image").onchange = function() {
            var file = document.getElementById("image").files[0]
            if (!file) return
                sign_request(file, function(response) {
                    upload(file, response.signed_request, response.url, function() {
                        document.getElementById("preview").src = response.url
                    });
                });
        };
        </script>
```

route:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

appRoutes.get('/sign', function(req, res){
    aws.config.update({accessKeyId: config.awsAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretAccessKey});

    var s3 = new aws.S3();
    var options = {
        Bucket: config.awsBucket,
        Key: req.query.file_name,
        Expires: 60,
        ContentType: req.query.file_type,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', options, function(err, data){
        if(err) return res.send('Error with S3')

        res.json({
            signed_request: data,
            url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + config.awsBucket + '/' + req.query.file_name
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think on the json you are sending back from `s3.getSignedUrl` method  the url should include your bucket, so it should be something like :

`url : 'https://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/ + ... `

Comment: Hey @fitims I changed my bucket, but still get the same requests and error

Comment: Actually determined that the issue was with the policy applied to the user with the auth key. Nothing to do with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was unrelated to the code and an issue with the permissions provided to the user with the auth key. After giving the user an AdministrativeAccess policy the issue was resolved.